# Carplay scenedelegate never called in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, appdelegate, carplay, uiscenedelegate

I am facing one issue where I have created a car play scene delegate file but it never gets executed.

Here is my code for the app

```
@main
struct FredScannerProApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is app delegate file

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      do
        {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
        // This will enable to show nowplaying controls on lock screen
        application.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        return true
        
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        if (connectingSceneSession.role == UISceneSession.Role.carTemplateApplication) {
            let scene =  UISceneConfiguration(name: "CarPlaySceneConfiguration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
            scene.delegateClass = CarPlaySceneDelegate.self
            return scene
        } else {
            return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is info plist file

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>CarPlaySceneConfiguration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarPlayDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Here is carplayscenedelegate file

```
class CarPlayDelegate: UIResponder {

    var carPlaymanager  = CarPlaySceneDelegate()


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        if scene is CPTemplateApplicationScene, session.configuration.name == "CarPlaySceneConfiguration" {
//            MemoryLogger.shared.appendEvent("Template application scene will connect.")
            print("Connected")
        }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }
}

extension CarPlayDelegate : CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate{

    /// Connects the root template to the CPInterfaceController.
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.carPlaymanager.connect(interfaceController)
    }
    
    // CarPlay disconnected
    private func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didDisconnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.carPlaymanager.disconnect()
    }
    
}
```

but somehow it's not attaching carplay instance
i don't know what's going on? If someone could help me in this. I really appreciate it.

Also, Let me know if you want demo project, I will provide same,

Thank you

Comment: What is the use of AppDelegate as you define a scene delegate in your info file and have a SwiftUI app ? You should have log in the debug console in xCode when you start your app from simulator or from CarPlay .